# Elementos iguais entre vetores - C

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver um problema desde cedo que é o seguinte:

> Uma escola deseja saber se existem alunos cursando simultaneamente as
>   disciplinas Lógica e  e Linguagem de programação. Coloque os números
>   das matrículas dos alunos que cursam a Lógica em um vetor, no máximo
>   de 5 alunos. Coloque os números das matrículas dos alunos que cursam
>   Linguagem em outro vetor, no máximo de 5 alunos. Mostre o número da
>   matrícula que aparece nos dois vetores.

Até está rodando porém quando coloco números fora de ordem está bugando. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço, pois estou quebrando a cabeça nessa questão e ela está me travando a concluir o resto das outras, parece ser preguiça de pensar, porém estou desde cedo travado nesta questão.

Desde-já agradeço

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int i, a;
int mat1[6], mat2[6];

int main(void){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    for(i=0 ; i<5; i++){

        printf("DIGITE AS MATRÍCULAS DOS ALUNOS DE LÓGICA DE PROGRAMAÇÃO: ");
        scanf("%d", &mat1[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){

        printf("DIGITE AS MATRÍCULAS DOS ALUNOS DE LINGUAGEM DE PROGRAMAÇÃO: ");
        scanf("%d", &mat2[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){

        for(a=5; a>=0; a--)
        {
            if(mat1[i] == mat2[a] || mat1[a] == mat2[i]) printf("AS MATRÍCULAS IGUAIS SÃO: %d\n", mat1[i]);
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Executando o programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você precisa "classificar" ou "ordenar" os arrays antes de fazer a comparação...como fazer a comparação ? existe uma função de biblioteca chamada "qsort" que faz isso...se você achar muito difícil usar "qsort", faça a ordenação manualmente, usando por exemplo o algoritmo "bubble sort"...e onde achar informações sobre "qsort" e "bubble sort" ? google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem vários erros pequenos no seu código, que lhe impossibilitam de obter o resultado que esperava. Repare que no segundo `for` que acha a matricula repetida a quantidade de elementos não é a mesma:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){    
//    ^----^ de 0 a 4 são 5 elementos
    for(a=5; a>=0; a--)
    //    ^-----^--- de 5 a 0 são 6 elementos
```

Aqui já vê que um `for` percorre 5 elementos e outro `6`. Para além disso ao aceder 6 elementos está a aceder a mais elementos dos que preencheu, e só não está a fazer um acesso inválido em memoria porque declarou os vetores com 6 casas, quando apenas precisava de 5. Isso também é algo que deve evitar fazer.

Também não tem necessidade de percorrer num for de forma crescente com `i++` e noutro decrescente com `a--`. Mais simples é fazer os dois normalmente de `0` a `4`.

A condição que tem `if(mat1[i] == mat2[a] || mat1[a] == mat2[i])` também não é o que precisa pois apenas necessita de validar se o elemento dado pelo primeiro `for` no vetor `mat1` é igual ao que está no vetor `mat2` com a variável do segundo `for`, ou seja, `if(mat1[i] == mat2[a])`.

Corrigindo o bloco de `fors` final já dá o resultado que espera:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(a=0; a<5; a++){
        if(mat1[i] == mat2[a]) printf("AS MATRÍCULAS IGUAIS SÃO: %d\n", mat1[i]);
    }
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/fg5ngU)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo, estou quebrando a cabeça nessa parte de vetores, brigadão mesmo.